AttributeError: module 'robot.api.logger' has no attribute 'LOGLEVEL'
Estou com o seguinte erro na execução do meu teste: Cadastrar o usuário criado na Serverest.
*** Settings ***
Library    RequestsLibrary
Library    String
Library    robot.api.logger
*** Variables ***
${BASE_URL}    https://serverest.dev
${EMAIL_TESTE}
*** Keywords ***
Criar um usuário novo
${gerador}    Generate Random String    length=8    chars=[LETTERS]
${random_string_lower}    Convert To Lower Case    ${gerador}
${EMAIL_TESTE}            Set Variable    ${random_string_lower}@email.com
# Log To Console            ${EMAIL_TESTE}
Cadastrar o usuário criado na Serverest
${body}    Create Dictionary    nome=Fulano da Silva
...                             email=${EMAIL_TESTE}
...                             password=1234
...                             administrador="TRUE"
# Log    chegou aqui: ${body}  
Criar Sessão na ServeRest

${RESPOSTA}    POST On Session    
...                               alias=ServeRest
...                               url=/usuarios  
...                               json=${body}  

Criar Sessão na ServeRest
${headers}    Create Dictionary    accept=application/json
...                                Content-Type=application/json
Create Session    alias=ServeRest    
...               url=https://serverest.dev
...               headers=${headers}
...               verify=False
Log    Sessão criada com sucesso para o endpoint: ${BASE_URL}    DEBUG

inserir a descrição da imagem aqui
